# Can height one maximal ideals in the normalization contract to non-height one primes in the base?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, normalization

Let $R$ be a local (Noetherian) integral domain of dimension greater than one.  Can the integral closure (i.e. normalization) of $R$ have a maximal ideal of height one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 2 of Appendix A1 of Nagata's "Local Rings" with $m = 0$ is an example of such a ring.

Comment: Thanks!  By the way, do you know of an example that is excellent (or at least universally catenary)?